# Reading nested attribute in data source (of a Cloud Run service that might not exist) in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I'm using Terraform v0.14.4 with GCP. I have a Cloud Run service that won't be managed with Terraform (it might exist or not), and I want to read its url.

If the service exists this works ok:

```
data "google_cloud_run_service" "myservice" {
  name = "myservice"
  location = "us-central1"
}

output "myservice" {
  value = data.google_cloud_run_service.myservice.status[0].url
}
```

But if it doesn't exist, I can't get it to work!. What I've tried:

- `data.google_cloud_run_service.myservice.*.status[*].url`

  status is null
- `length(data.google_cloud_run_service.myservice) > 0 ? data.google_cloud_run_service.myservice.*.status[0].url : ""`
- Tried with `join("", data.google_cloud_run_service.myservice.*.status)`

  I get this error: `data.google_cloud_run_service.myservice is object with 9 attributes`
- `coalescelist(data.google_cloud_run_service.myservice.*.status, <...>)`

  It just returns [null], and using `compact` over the result gets me a `Invalid value for "list" parameter: element 0: string required.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are working against the design of this data source a little here, but based on the error messages you've shown it seems like the behavior is that `status` is null when the requested object doesn't exist and is a list when it does, and so you'll need to write an expression that can deal with both situations.

Here's my attempt, based only on the documentation of the resource along with some assumptions I'm making based on the error message you included:

```
output "myservice" {
  value = (
    data.google_cloud_run_service.myservice.status != null ?
    data.google_cloud_run_service.myservice.status[0].url :
    null
  )
}
```

There is another potentially-shorter way to write that, relying on [the `try` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/try.html)'s ability to catch dynamic errors and return a fallback value, although this does go against the recommendations in the documentation in that it forces an unfamiliar future reader to do a bit more guesswork to understand in which situations the expression might succeed and which it might return the fallback:

```
output "myservice" {
  value = try(data.google_cloud_run_service.myservice.status[0].url, null)
}
```